# Is SQL how to get a value of a column of table from a datetime range of another table?

Tags: sql

I have a one-person schedule table with rows that represent time intervals with one taking office. Functions may change from interval to interval. I have another table where the person performs an action at a specific time. I would like to recover its function which is in the first table from the time of the action of the second table.

**the first query give me for the first table :**

```
SELECT itr.[user_number]
      ,rt.[STARTED_ON] as task_started_on
      ,rt.[ENDED_ON] as task_ended_on
      ,tr.[tr_number]
      ,ttf.[DESC_NL] as tm_function
  FROM [TM] itr
INNER JOIN [RT] rt ON rt.[TM_IDENT_NUM] = itr.[TM_IDENT_NUM]
LEFT JOIN [TTF] ttf ON ttf.[TTF_ID] = rt.[TTF_ID]
LEFT JOIN [TR] tr ON tr.[TR_ID] = rt.[TR_ID]
WHERE itr.user_number IS NOT NULL
AND rt.[STARTED_ON] >= '2021-02-12 00:00:00' AND rt.[STARTED_ON] <= '2021-02-12 23:59:59'
AND itr.[user_number] = 'abcd'
AND tr.[TR_ID] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY rt.[STARTED_ON] ASC
```

| user_number | task_started_on | task_ended_on | tr_number | tm_function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 12-02-21 10:56 | 12-02-21 11:53 | 1862 | control |
| abcd | 12-02-21 ***11:53*** | 12-02-21 ***13:03*** | ***1883*** | ***control*** |
| abcd | 12-02-21 13:03 | 12-02-21 13:03 | 1883 | chief |
| abcd | 12-02-21 13:03 | 12-02-21 13:10 | 4114 | chief |
| abcd | 12-02-21 13:10 | 12-02-21 15:14 | 4114 | chief |
| abcd | 12-02-21 15:46 | 12-02-21 17:02 | 4138 | control |

**the second query from my table 2 give me :**

```
SELECT [C170_ID]
      ,[tr_number]
      ,[CREATED_ON]
      ,[user_number]
  FROM [C170] c170
  inner join [TM] as tm on tm.USER_NAME = c170.MSL_USER
  WHERE c170.CREATED_ON >= '2021-02-12 00:00:00' AND C170.CREATED_ON <= '2021-02-12 23:59:59'
  AND SUCCES_FLAG = '1'
  AND MSL_USER = 'abcd'
  ORDER BY CREATED_ON ASC
```

| C170_ID | tr_number | CREATED_ON | user_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5E646F45 | ***1883*** | 12-02-21 ***12:26*** | abcd |

**and I would like to have this result :**

| C170_ID | tr_number | CREATED_ON | user_number | tm_function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5E646F45 | 1883 | 12-02-21 12:26 | abcd | control |

How can I modify my second query so that it returns tm_function as well?

Comment: Please always add the database that you are using (Any  of: mssql, postgresql, sqlite, db2 of even sql-server if you use the Microsoft thing)

Comment: The definition of the relevant tables would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tm_function is referred to as `ttf.[DESC_NL]`, you will need to join ttf to your second query. Since you have not shared your table structures, we can only guess about them. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT [C170_ID]
      ,[tr_number]
      ,[CREATED_ON]
      ,[user_number]
      ,ttf.[DESC_NL]
  FROM [C170] c170
  inner join [TM] as itr on itr.USER_NAME = c170.MSL_USER
  inner join [TTF] as ttf on itr.[TTF_ID] = ttf.[TTF_IF] and c170.[CREATED_ON] BETWEEN ttf.task_started_on AND ttf.task_ended_on
  WHERE c170.CREATED_ON >= '2021-02-12 00:00:00' AND C170.CREATED_ON <= '2021-02-12 23:59:59'
  AND SUCCES_FLAG = '1'
  AND MSL_USER = 'abcd'
  ORDER BY CREATED_ON ASC
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the help ! Especially since I didn't have to think about setting the tables and their relations.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT [C170_ID]
      ,[tr_number]
      ,[CREATED_ON]
      ,[user_number]
      ,ttf.[DESC_NL] as tm_function
  FROM [C170] c170
  inner join [TM] as tm on tm.USER_NAME = c170.MSL_USER

  INNER JOIN [RT] rt ON rt.[TM_IDENT_NUM] = itr.[TM_IDENT_NUM]
  LEFT JOIN [TTF] ttf ON ttf.[TTF_ID] = rt.[TTF_ID]

  WHERE c170.CREATED_ON >= '2021-02-12 00:00:00' AND C170.CREATED_ON <= '2021-02-12 23:59:59'
  AND SUCCES_FLAG = '1'
  AND MSL_USER = 'abcd'
  ORDER BY CREATED_ON ASC
```

above is untested, but should work...